# Receding and Protruding menu tabs Jquery

Tags: jquery

Sorry if this is a silly question but I have been on web design for 2 weeks and I am trying to make some menu tabs. Specificity ones that protrude when you mouseover and recede back to start position when mouseleave. I have made some code but it seems to act strangely.
When I mouse over its fine and the tab comes down 10px but when I leave the second time on any tab it recedes 10px then another 10px and it adds up each time incrementally, 20, 30, 40 etc.

I have tried popping in a stop even propergation but I am still learning. If its messy let me know.

Here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.buttons').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).animate({top: '+=10'}, 200, function() {
   $(this).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({top: '+=-10'}, 200, function() {

    });
   });
  });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/thewebdes/DqfJ5/

Is that what you were after?

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="buttons">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="buttons">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="buttons">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
body { font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; }
li { float: left; display: inline; margin: 0 1px 0 0; }
a:link, a:visited { position: relative; display: block; padding: 5px 10px; text-decoration: none; color: #39F; background: #039; border: 1px solid #03C; }
a:hover, a:active { color: #F90; background: #960; border: 1px solid #630; }
```

JS

```
$('.buttons').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({top: '-=10', paddingBottom: '15px'}, 200);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({top: '+=10', paddingBottom: '5px'}, 200);
});
```

-- edit to answer comment --

If you don't want the text to move:

```
$('.buttons').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({paddingBottom: '15px'}, 200);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({paddingBottom: '5px'}, 200);
});
```

If you do:

```
$('.buttons').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({paddingTop: '15px'}, 200);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({paddingTop: '5px'}, 200);
});
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks. Do I just swap terms for top and bottom in the Jquery script if I want the animation to be downwards opposed to upwards?

Comment: I'll give you a hand: The `stop(true,true)` stops the hover effect from triggering over and over if you wave your cursor over it loads of times. The `top-=10` makes the container move up 10px and I add 10px of padding to the bottom to make the bottom site where it originally was. This is reversed by removing the 10px from the top and the 10px from the padding. The one where it moves down is simply adding padding. The text will stay where it is if you pad the bottom, the text will move if you pad the top. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Scott.
That makes sense in on conceptual level I am sure as my knowledge grows I will be able to implement it practically from memory.

Comment: It all comes with practice and looking at what other people have done. I'm glad to have helped you on your way :)